# how to install the ssl module for python 2.7.17 on opensuse (SLES) 15 SP2?

Tags: python-2.7, ssl, openssl, opensuse, sles

I have installed OpenSSL and python2-pyOpenSSL-17.5.0-lp152.6.2.noarch.rpm in my SLES machine and still, I am getting the following error:

1. import ssl inside python CLI

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
> ImportError: No module named ssl
> ```

2. pip install numpy gives the following error:

> ```
> pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
> ```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to install `libopenssl-devel` package